# Calcluated Column multiple IF with SEARCH statement coming up as #Name?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, javascript, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I want to search each cell in a column for a certain pharse. I figure I should use IF statements but since the following text can be anything I need to incorporate a SEARCH statement as well. Like at my sample code below.

```
=IF(SEARCH("up",status_value),("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:green;'></div>")
,IF(SEARCH("Down",status_value),("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:yellow;'></div>")
,IF(SEARCH("Degraded",status_value),("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:red;'></div>")
,IF(SEARCH("100-90",status_value),("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:green;'></div>")
,IF(SEARCH("89-80",status_value),("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:yellow;'></div>")
,IF(SEARCH("79-70",status_value),("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:red;'></div>")
,IF(SEARCH("<10",status_value),("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:blue;'></div>"),"")))))))
```

So as you see the status column corresponds to the status_values col.
It allows me to have this in the calculated column but when it renders up initially  as
[image]

If I change the value in status_values then there should be a different colored circle it comes up as #Name? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("up",status_value))=false,("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:green;'></div>")
,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Down",status_value))=false,("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:yellow;'></div>")
,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Degraded",status_value))=false,("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:red;'></div>")
,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("100-90",status_value))=false,("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:green;'></div>")
,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("89-80",status_value))=false,("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:yellow;'></div>")
,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("79-70",status_value))=false,("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:red;'></div>")
,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("<10",status_value))=false,("<div style='width:25px; height:25px; border-radius:25px; background-color:blue;'></div>"),"")))))))
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: If my answer helps you, you could accept it as answer:)

Comment: (: 
Of course! Thank you!

Comment: You could refer to this to mark an answer as accepted: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers